# Nginx Reverse Proxy to S3 Private Bucket

Tags: authentication, nginx, amazon-s3, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using ngx_aws_auth module to authenticate to S3 Private Bucket with AWS Signature V4

I've generated the scope and the signature using the python script and hardcoded into my NGINX to test, but AWS response says that the signature expected doesn't match

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

I'm stucked into this somedays and I really don't know what more I can do.

I'm using ./script -k my-aws-secret-key -r my-aws-region -s my-aws-service, it returns the right scope and the signature and the I'm copying and pasting into nginx to use it.

```
`location /test {
    aws_access_key AKIAEXAMPLETEST;
    aws_s3_bucket my-test-bucket;
    aws_key_scope 20230630/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request;
    aws_signing_key SOMERANDOMVALUE=;
    aws_sign;
    proxy_pass http://my-test-bucket/my-test-file.mp4
}`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share what is the business requirement behind this? It would help us recommend some solutions

Comment: Sure, I have to access my files that are in a private bucket and proxy it. Actually, I'm using Kaltura/nginx-vod-module and I need to get MP4 files into private S3 Bucket and then repack it to HLS Inflight